# Find minimum of an expression $f(q) = log_2(q^q \cdot (n-q+1)^{n-q+1})$

Tags: functions, derivatives, maxima-minima

I have that following expression:

$$
f(q) = log_2(q^q \cdot (n-q+1)^{n-q+1})
$$

The solution says it has a min at

$$
q = (n+1)/2
$$

Is there a strait way to get to this min?

When i try to take the derivate it becomes complicated (or i miss something)?

Anyway, how did they get to this min?

Comment: Symmetry? And if you differentiate, I think you will find $\log q - \log(n+1-q)$ is factor of $f'(q)$, which implies the minimum is at $q=(n+1)/2$.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(q)=\log_2(q^q \cdot (n-q+1)^{n-q+1} )\\ = q\log_2 q + (n-q+1)\log_2 (n-q+1)$$

$$f’(q) = q\cdot \frac 1q + \log _2 (q) \frac{1}{\ln 2} - (n-q+1) \cdot \frac{1}{n-q+1} - \log_2(n-q+1) \frac{1}{\ln 2}=0 \\ \implies \log_2(q) = \log_2(n-q+1) \\ \implies q=\frac{n+1}{2}$$